# kivy move image only when image is pressed

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making a game in kivy where when you press on the soccer ball it moves. I want the ball to move only when I press exactly on the ball, if I press anywhere else it shouldn't move. Currently, the ball moves if I press anywhere close to the ball which Is not what I want. Is there anything I can do so that it only moves when I press exactly on the ball? Below is my code!

main.py

```
class Ball(Image):
velocity = NumericProperty(0)


def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        self.source = "icons/ball.png"
        self.velocity = 275
    return super().on_touch_down(touch)

def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        self.source = "icons/ball.png"
    return super().on_touch_up(touch)


class MainApp(App):
    GRAVITY = 300


def move_ball(self, time_passed):
    ball = self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.ball
    ball.y = ball.y + ball.velocity * time_passed
    ball.velocity = ball.velocity - self.GRAVITY * time_passed


def start_game(self):
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.move_ball, 1/60.)
```

kivy code

```
#:import utils kivy.utils


<GameScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#39B3F2")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Image:
            source: "icons/sun.png"
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
        size_hint: 1, .2
        Image:
            source: "icons/clouds.png"
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        pos_hint: {"bottom": 1, "left": 1}
        size_hint: 1, .5
        Image:
            source: "icons/Field4.png"
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
            pos: self.pos


    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
        font_size: dp(20)
        font_name: 'SackersGothicStd-Medium.otf'
        text: "Start Game"
        color: "gold"
        pos_hint: { "center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.3}
        size: 150, 55
        size_hint: None, None
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (57/255.0, 179/255.0, 242/255.0, .10)


        on_release:
            self.disabled = True
            self.opacity = 0
            root.play_sound()
            app.start_game()


    Ball:
        source: "icons/ball.png"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 500, 500
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
        id: ball
```

I also tried  keep_ratio: True
allow_stretch: True
but it still didn't work

Comment: `ball` is a `circle` which has some `radius` - if you check distance `ball_center - mouse_position <= radius` then you clicked inside this `circle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ball` is a `circle` (or rather `disk`) which has some `radius` - if you check distance between `ball center` and `mouse position` and it is smaller then `radius` then you clicked inside this `circle` or `disk`.

More precisely using the [Pythagorean formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) `a**2 + b**2 == c**2`
or rather [disk's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_(mathematics)) : `x**2 + y**2 <= r**2`

```
(ball.centerx - touch.pos.x)**2 + (ball.centery - touch.pos.y)**2 <= radius**2
```

Kivy has class [Vector](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.vector.html) to make it simpler - but I can't test it.

```
Vector(ball.center).distance(touch.pos) <= radius
```

And you should use it instead of `collide_point()`

```
class Ball(Image):

    velocity = NumericProperty(0)
 
    radius = 50  # you have to get it manually from image     
    
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if Vector(self.center).distance(touch.pos) <= radius:
            self.source = "icons/ball.png"
            self.velocity = 275

        return super().on_touch_down(touch)
    
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if Vector(self.center).distance(touch.pos) <= radius:
            self.source = "icons/ball.png"

        return super().on_touch_up(touch)
```

---

I'm not sure but maybe it even keeps ball position as `Vector()` and you could use directly

```
ball.center.distance(touch.pos) <= radius
```

Comment: Where do I put this code?

Comment: instead of `collide_point()`

Comment: BTW: kivy has class [Vector](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.vector.html) to make it simpler. `Vector(ball.center).distance(mouse) <= radius**2`

Comment: I tried it, but it says "if Vector(self.center).distance(touch.pos) <= radius:
 NameError: name 'Vector' is not defined"

Comment: you have to import this class `Vector` from `kivy.vector`. Documentation in my link [Vector](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.vector.html) even show at the top: `Module: kivy.vector`

Comment: BTW: if you would create minimal working code in question then I could test it but I don't have code for test it.

Comment: I did "from kivy.vector import Vector" now it shows this error "if Vector(self.center).distance(touch.pos) <= radius:
 NameError: name 'radius' is not defined"

Comment: you have to defined this variable with correct value - I don't know how big is your ball on image.

Comment: Thank You so much! I got it now!

Comment: hey I would like to play a sound whenever "on_touch_down" is pressed how can I do that?

Comment: Kivy doc: [Audio](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.audio.html)

Comment: I looked at it but didn't find a solution! can you please help!

Comment: I don't understand, at the top you have example which explains everything. `sound = SoundLoader.load('mytest.wav')` and `sound.play()`. And you should use it in function `on_touch_down`. Eventually you could `load` file only once - in `__init__` - and use `self.sound` instead of `sound`

Comment: I solved the issue. Now I'm trying to lower the sound volume and I tried using "sound.volume = 0.5" but this doesn't work, can you help? For more information check my new post! Thank You!